# Can't connect to specific network (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: wireless, 16.04

My laptop (Acer E5-523) detects all nearby wifi networks but won't connect to my home network, it keeps asking me to enter the password although I'm completely sure it is correct.

My network adapter is a qualcomm atheros qca9377 and at first I thought it was a driver problem and tried many things without success, until I tried to connect to my phone wifi network and it worked. I have other laptops with linux installed and all can connect to my home network without a problem.

I really need to use linux and this is a major setback for me. I know there are similar questions to this one but nothing has worked for me.

Comment: Is it possible that your computer is getting a weak wifi signal through some combination of its wifi hardware and distance? Can you move your laptop closer to the router and try again?

Comment: Literally my laptop is next to the router. I do get a connection by using ethernet.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  However, its not my network, it's a clients network.  I'm also running Ubuntu 16.04.  The signal is strong.  I'm in the same room with the router.  My Ubuntu computer is the only computer that has the problem.  All the other computers and devices connects flawlessly.

Comment: Do you have the same network adapter? I never solved this problem. I had to get my router changed.